# Integral of $\int \frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{1+e^x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help to solve this:

$$\int \frac{xe^x}{\sqrt{1+e^x}} dx$$

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! You can ask all kinds of questions so long as they're related to mathematics. However, note that *it's always advised to include your attempt and where you got stuck*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $u=\sqrt{1+e^x}$ and $du=\dfrac{e^xdx}{2\sqrt{1+e^x}}$

This transforms the integral to

$$2\int \ln(u^2-1)du=2\int \ln((u+1)(u-1))du=2\int \ln(u+1)+2\int\ln(u-1)du$$

Now, try integration by parts.

Comment: Yes, thank you for editing.